# multidimensional array matrix php

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a multidimensional array in order to put it into a database MYSQL with this format:

```
create table var
(
fecha DATE not null,
hora TIME not null, DD2
float(5,2),
RGD float(5,2),
RGA float(5,2),
FLU float(5,2),
H2O float(5,2),
PRES_U float(5,2),
U float(5,2),
V float(5,2),
Ts float(5,2),
T1 float(5,2),
T2 float(5,2),
H1 float(5,2), 
H2 float(5,2),
HS float(5,2),
VV1 float(5,2),
VV2 float(5,2));
```

In PHP i created this array

```
$dataarray=array(array("FECHAS",date("Y-m-d")), array("HORAS",date("H:i:s")),
array("RGD",0), array("RGA",0),
array("FLU",0),array("DD2",0),array("H20",0),array("PRES:U",0),array("U",0),array("V",0),
array("TS",0), array("T1",0),           array("T2",0),array("H1",0),
array("H2",0),array("HS",0),array("VV1",0),array("VV2",0) );
```

the data I had looked like this:

```
2014-02-23,19:46:33,RGD,-5.36;
2014-02-23,19:50:51,FLU,0.34;
2014-02-23,19:55:11,PRES:U,93.83;
2014-02-23,19:57:20,U,0.66;
2014-02-23,19:59:25,V,-1.93;
2014-02-23,20:05:54,T2,7.79;
2014-02-23,20:08:04,H1,75.02;
2014-02-23,20:10:15,H2,40.18;
2014-02-23,20:12:22,HS,-0.07;
2014-02-23,20:16:40,VV2,-2.06;
2014-02-23,20:20:56,RGD,-4.58;
2014-02-23,20:23:09,RGA,1.44;
2014-02-23,20:27:23,H2O,-0.0;
2014-02-23,20:33:55,V,2.04;
```

now i have them almost ready to put into the database and they look like this:

```
2014-02-23 19:46:33 -5.36 0 0.34 0 0 93.83 0.66 -1.93 0 0 7.79 75.0240.18 -0.07 0 0 
2014-02-23 20:16:40 -4.58 1.44 0 0 0 0 0 2.04 0 3.47 0 90.99 0 0 0 -2.06
```

But as you can see I work with $dataarray[0][1], etc but the programm doesn't allow me to create something like $dataarray[$j]
so i can have access to the lines.

how can i do it? any suggestions? also if you have comments about please add them.

I will explain myself little bit more. I need to work with array like this

$dataarray[$j][0][1].... and pass this to my MYSQL database, because i'm intersted in putting data in string format as you can see in the last example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you are trying this way, but from what I understand from you code you could use an associative array like this:

```
$dataarray=array("FECHAS" => date("Y-m-d"),
                 "HORAS" => date("H:i:s"),
                 "RGD" => 0,
                 "RGA" => 0,
                 "FLU" => 0,
                 "DD2" => 0,
                 "H20" => 0,
                 "PRES:U" => 0,
                 "U" => 0,
                 "V" => 0,
                 "TS" => 0,
                 "T1" => 0,
                 "T2" => 0,
                 "H1" => 0,
                 "H2" => 0,
                 "HS" => 0,
                 "VV1" => 0,
                 "VV2" => 0);
```

and then something like:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO var (FECHAS, HORAS, RGD, ...) VALUES (".$dataarray["FECHAS"].",.....);
```

or if you want to use a loop for more automation

```
$keys, $vals;
foreach($dataarray as $k => $v){
    $keys.= $k.",";
    $vars.= $v."','";
}
mysql_query("INSERT INTO var (".$keys.") VALUES (".$vars.");
```

Note: The above is not 100% valid code, I could not try it at the moment so it'll require a little bit of fixing

Comment: Ok, I was able to change everything and works perfectly fine, also now i can work with multilevel array like you suggested: $dataarray[$j]["FECHA"]. :) now i'll have to fight with my database to find it on my laptop and put data into it from my page but still thanks a lot.